# Как разбить вектор заранее неизвестной длины на равные части (создать другие вектора)

Tags: c++, массивы, vector

У меня есть обычный вектор целочисленных значений 'vector v'. Он заполняется значениями пользователем, причем размерность вектора после заполнения будет ровно делиться на 6. Мне нужно разбить этот вектор на столько векторов, сколько есть в нём групп по 6 чисел.
Например, если пользователь ввел 12 чисел, то вектор нужно разбить на 2 вектора по 6 чисел в каждом; если 24 числа, то на 4 вектора и т.д.
Подскажите пожалуйста, искала, но не могу найти(
Сложность в том, что даже после того, как пользователь всё ввел, я могу определить, сколько векторов мне понадобится, написав "a = v.size() / 6", но не знаю, как разбить этот вектор на это число в цикле.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<vector>

    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        int a;
        vector<int> v1;

        for (cin; ; ) { //получение всех значений
            cin >> a;
            if (a == -1) {
                break;
            }
            v1.push_back(a);
        }

        int size = v1.size() / 6; //количество векторов, на которые нужно разбить вектор
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { //разбиение вектора

        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: У вас код уже есть какой нибудь ? Добавьте, есть так

Comment: В каком виде вам нужен результат? `vector<vector<int>>` годится или нет?

Comment: @Harry годится, вид любой, главное, чтобы он делал то, что нужно)

Comment: @GinTasan добавила

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Вот](https://ideone.com/7J4Pr4).

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<int> v;

    for(int a; cin >> a ; )
    {
        if (a == -1)  break;
        v.push_back(a);
    }

    vector<vector<int>> res(v.size()/6);

    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        res[i/6].push_back(v[i]);
    }

    for(auto& w: res)
    {
        for(auto i: w) cout << i << " "; cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое!